# Android: Different Background Image/Shape drawable for the ExpandedListview's child item

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

How to set Different Background Image/Shape drawable for the ExpandedListview's child item when  expanded?

Comment: Please be more specific or noone can help you!!!

Comment: Hi i want each Child after expanding group should have same background image only for the expanded listview(child listview) not for header of the group.how can i do that in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Check in the getChildView method of your custom adapter. Base on the condition, set the back groud for your child views properly.Check this out:

```
@Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View childView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item, null);
            if(groupPosition == 0){
                childView.setBackgroundResource(R.id.background_a);
            }else{
                childView.setBackgroundResource(R.id.background_b);
            }
            return childView;
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply,this will set background for only one row.I want list containing child rows have one background.Means i want complete expanded view should have one background.what we can do for that?

Comment: As far I as know, ExpandableListView doesn't support such a customisation, I'm afraid that you have to create your own layout to do that. You could use ListView and make a group-children view as an item of your ListView, customise that item view. Hope this helps.